# What do we mean by flattening of WSDL file?

Tags: wsdl, flatten

Flattening of web service description language file refers to which process?

Answer (score 0):

When we use it, flatten = removing links to external schema.

Comment: Is this a question? If yes then I'd say no, cause I needed not a specific answer but a generalized answer regarding flattening of a file. If there can't be generalized answer then this is okay. Besides what's the use of this and where do we do this?